# How to replace special characters except - (dash)

Tags: sql, postgresql, regexp-replace

Using PGAdmin (Postgresql), I'm trying to remove all special characters except the - in the fields.

Current command being used:

```
regexp_replace(b.DOWNCASE_NAME, '[^\w\s]', '', 'g') as CONDITION_NAME_DC,
```

That will change "ovarian sertoli-leydig cell tumor" to "ovarian sertolileydig cell tumor"

I used this because there are fields which contain commas, forward slashes and I don't need those. But how do I use regexp_replace to remove those characters except for the - ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the `-` in the pattern using `^-` as shown below

```
select regexp_replace('ova@ri/an serto#li-leydi!g cel/l tumor', '[^\w\s^-]', '', 'g')
```

Output

```
ovarian sertoli-leydig cell tumor
```

[**Check demo here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9e9f7864453cf1939206ae5712e1e3fa)

Comment: This works great! Thanks! I have a follow up question if you don't mind. I noticed that in my original regexp_replace command, it would correctly turn cancer/brca1 into cancer brca1. But for ovarian sertoli-leydig cell tumor it would make it  ovarian sertolileydig cell tumor. How come for this one it is merging the two words together instead of keeping a space in between them like it does for the one i mentioned before?

Comment: Does it? For me  `select regexp_replace('cancer/brca1', '[^\w\s]', '', 'g') ` is giving `cancerbrca1` - without space

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use like this-

```
 preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/', '', $yourString);
```